# I don't understand the "0" in [0].selectedIndex

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain what the `[0]` represents in the following code?

```
$('#cars')[0].selectedIndex=0;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$(#cars)` returns an array of all of the elements with id="cars". The `[0]` chooses the first element of that array. It's like saying "Give me a list of all of the items on the page with 'cars' as the ID." This will probably be a list that only has 1 item in it. The `[0]` is saying "out of this list, pick the first item." I would suggest searching for Arrays in Javascript, and learning how they work.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Selector returns an array of elements/nodes every time.

So `$(".example")` will return an array containing elements matching that selector.

In your case there may be only one element having that class name but the jQuery operates on array of elements under the hood so it will return an array containing an element on index `0`.

So in javascript you can access an element from an array using index. (in your case the 0 index)

Comment: ok, so if the [0] refers to indexing in an array , what does the .SelectedIndex = 0 refer to ?

Comment: `SelectedIndex`  is a property of `<select>` element of html. more information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $ function to select multiple elements. For example, `$(".example")` will select all of the elements that have the `example` class.
Using [0] will return the first element as a DOM node (not as a jQuery object).

Comment: Each jQuery object presents itself as an object with all the powerful jQuery methods and at the same time it almost appears like an "normal" array with the individual selected DOM elements in it. You  get the `.length` property but not the typical `Array.prototype` methods a JavaScript array has.

Comment: In addition to cars10m's comment, also avoid for-in loops with jquery objects, because they aren't arrays.

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros Do `for of` loops work? Does JQuery have an iterator for newer javascript?

Comment: @Garrett Motzner Yes, you can use the .each method. https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros I was thinking more like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Iterating_over_other_iterable_objects. Does it conform to that interface?